# AS3: A term is undefined

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

All right so the first piece of code here is for when the user is re-selecting a button for it to clear and then set the Array spot to a blank number. The second piece is where the issue is with the error A term is undefined. Now i haven't had this issue until I added the first piece.

```
if(tempArray[1] == pickFive[0]){
            Game.BARR.balls.balls2.b1.num1.text = '';
            pickFive.splice(pickFive.indexOf(tempArray[1]), 1);
            pickFive[0] = ("");
        }
if(pickFive[0] != null){
        //trace(Game.NumberBoard_mc.Pick5['btn_' + pickFive[0]].name);
        Game.NumberBoard_mc.Pick5['btn_' + pickFive[0]].gotoAndStop(2);//Saying this line
        Game.BARR.balls.balls2.b1.num1.text = pickFive[0];
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be pickFive.push('')?

Comment: that makes it run but i need it to be in that array spot of [0].

Comment: If you're always adding at the beginning of the array, you can use unshift: pickFive.unshift(''); You can also take a look at the splice method for adding an element anywhere in the array. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice()

Comment: Thanks for the help that will always work for this index number, but I will eventually need to add it to index slots 1-4.

Comment: With splice you can add more than 1 element starting from a specified startIndex. So, it shouldn't be a problem if you need to add consecutive elements by doing something like pickFive.splice(0, 0, '', '', '', '');

Comment: Not really sure you mean there @CristinaGeorgescu. Sorry a little new to as3 still

Comment: You can read more here (step 8 precisely): http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/as3-101-arrays-basix--active-1703 Splice is a powerful method for both deleting and adding elements. You have to figure out how do you want to delete and add elements in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (pickFive.indexOf(tempArray[1]) != -1) {
        if(event.target.currentFrame == 2) {
            event.target.gotoAndStop(1);
            }
        if(tempArray[1] == pickFive[0]){
            Game.BARR.balls.balls2.b1.num1.text = '';
            pickFive[0] = "";
        }
if(pickFive[0] != null){
    if(pickFive[0] != ""){
    Game.NumberBoard_mc.Pick5['btn_' + pickFive[0]].gotoAndStop(2);
    Game.BARR.balls.balls2.b1.num1.text = pickFive[0];
    }
  }
```